# Cloudfront returning 404 randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Some users see 404 when they try loading my website on their devices, while it works fine for others. The website was uploaded to AWS s3 and then linked to cloudfront. The domain was purchased on namecheap and i pointed it to AWS route 53.
So far i have disabled caching on cloudfront and redirected the 404 error page to the the actual homepage, but few users are still reporting the same issue.

Comment: Did you force cache invalidation for the concerned files? ex: ```aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ...```

Comment: yes i created invalidations

Comment: @redala do you have any sugestions?